# Will android 13 release will effect android 12 targetted apps

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, android-12

My app targets android 12 when android 13 launches will my app gets crashed due to latest features in android 13 or it will be stable till i change target of my app to android 13.

I assume that unless we update to android 13 its features should not effect android 12 targeted apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't. I had similar issue when Android 12 required PendingIntents to have specified mutability flag. It haven't crashed even on Android 12 devices until I upgraded targetSdk - after an upgrade it started crashing :)

Comment: Ok Will mark this as accepted after sometime as i want to hear other answers too i have same assessment just like you

Comment: @RockyGlobal found this now: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-all
There are some changes that might crash the app (like runtime permissions for notifications). I think the most reliable way to check it would be to run your app on Android 13 emulator

Comment: Even if our app target android 12 will push notifications crash on android 13 devices ?

Comment: I'm not saying that it will, but it might. You simply need to check it on emulator. I bet that it will not crash in this case but you never know until you check it :D

Comment: Ya sure will check once

Answer (score 0):

For all who are visiting this question i want to specify that

Yes android 13 has a notification permission change which will effect all the apps irrespective whether you target android 13 or not.

So please be alert and change / add required things to explain user why they should turn on notifications.

Reason:
Till android 12 notifications were turned on by default

From android 13 users need to turn on notifications by default turned off.